# How to deal with underful vbox caused by formulas or floats?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, double-sided

In `twoside` documents, `\flushbottom` is automatically active in the KOMA classes. This works fine, as long as the text is filling all pages from top to bottom and formulas only appear in the middle of pages, as in this MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\par
\[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\]
\end{document}
```

That document compiles without warnings and the result looks decent. Sometimes, however, formulas appear close to a page break as in this MWE tuned to show the effect.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\par
\lipsum[1][1]
\par
\[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\]
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains that it cannot fill the page, resulting in an underfull `vbox`.

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active
```

The result looks unpleasant with big gaps between the paragraphs, caused by the formula forced to the second page. Similar cases happen, when floats are included into the document, causing many underfull `vbox`es for my document.

[image: Underfull vbox with formula]

From a typographic point of view, is there a preferred solution to this situation? I can think of three possible approaches:

1. Live with it the way it is and ignore the underfull `vbox` warnings.
2. Turn off `\flushbottom`. I personally don't think this is a good solution in a two-sided document.
3. Make LaTeX increase the line spread on the affected pages to distribute the effect more evenly. I personally believe this is the optically most pleasing approach. What length would I need to modify for that? Do I need to include a rubber length to `\linespread` or so?

Is there an accepted typographical best practice for this scenario?

---

Edit: Note that in this case the issue can be resolved by changing line breaks, causing a different number of lines in some paragraphs, as pointed out by David. This, however, is almost never the case for underfull `vbox`es caused by floats (i.e. images) with a height that is not a multiple of `\baselineskip`. The following MWE illustrates this case.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][25.2\baselineskip][c]{0.9\textwidth}\centering xxx\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Here, also, LaTeX complains about an underfull `vbox` and the paragraphs look stretched in the output.

[image: Underfull vbox with float]

Comment: note that you should never have a blank line or `\par` before a display math (it forces a white line of text and bad spacing)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed it when composing the MWE. I'll leave it like that now, since you specifically address the issue in your answer.

Comment: Your comment about floats would not apply with usual setting, as you normally have stretchy length added between a top float and the page content so that would never normally cause an underfull box.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It does for me on almost any page. I guess, I'll have to dig for the origin then.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your comment about the stretchy length for floats is true, but it seems that the default rubber is too small. I'll add another answer addressing this.

Comment: ah yes. 2pt is not really enough for this case

Answer (score 1):

The example document is in error as there should never be a paragraph break before a math display.

However the same issue arrises with

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\par
\lipsum[1][1]
\par
zzz
\[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\]
\end{document}
```

where you see that the anomalous space at the top page 2 in the original isn't vertical space but is in fact a "white line" of a paragraph so not dropped at the page break, here that line has visible text.

There are various things you can do if you are able to assert manual control, for example

1. use `\enlargethispage` to adjust the page height by +/- `\baselineskip` to get a better break, in this case it is best to do it on both pages of a two-page spread
2. rewrite the text to better fit.
3. use `\looseness` on larger paragraphs were there is flexibility in line breaking decisions to make them take a line more or less, this works here for example

   ```
   \documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \begin{document}
   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[1]

   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[2]

   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[3]

   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[4]

   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[5]


   \looseness=1
   \lipsum[1]

   zzz
   \[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\]
   \end{document}
   ```

---

Of the options that you mention 3 is the least desirable (not really an option) changing the linespacing from page to page would be incredibly distracting.

Comment: If I understand correclty, option 1 is like `\raggedbottom`, just for a single page. As stated in the question, I don't think this looks nice in a two-sided document. Would you, personally, differ in that point? Actually, 2 and 3 are not a proper solution for the case where a float is the issue: It often happens to me that the float (say an image) has a height of about n + 0.5 lines of text. So I will never be able to resolve the issue by restructuring my text or having more linebreaks. For that case, could I achieve a bigger linespread with a rubber length?

Comment: Added an edit to clarify my point.

Comment: @ranguwud no it is not like raggedbottom which would leave the bottom lines at an arbitrary place, if you increase both pages on a two page spread by 1 baselineskip then the visible bottom baselines of the spread will be aligned, just that the page is a line shorter or longer. If you read the production notes of the latex companion book for example that was done on dozens of pages, as the large boxed examples made page breaking difficult to be fully automatic.

Comment: @ranguwud I think changing the interline spacing should be an absolute last resort (actually normally I wouldn't consider it an option at all)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518073/77970) of David nicely addresses the case where underfull `vbox`es are caused by formulas. For the case of floats there is a different approach. The length `\textfloatsep` (amogst others) controls the separation of figures and text. This length is flexible by default, but the flexibility is too small for the case presented in the question. By default, the value seems to be

```
20.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt
```

To avoid stretching between paragraphs, the flexibility should be at least the value of `\baselineskip`. This can be achieved by a setting like the following.

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1.25\baselineskip plus 0.4\baselineskip minus 0.6\baselineskip}
```